# NextJS: Build components to export and pull into a different project

Tags: next.js, package.json, tsconfig, private-repository

**Current Setup:** I have two NextJS apps: one we'll call Project A and a library repo that we'll call Project LIB. Project A is a fairly simple app that has a couple independent components whereas Project LIB is a library-like app that many other apps leverage.

**What I am trying to do:** Package up Project A in a way where the build distribution contains all of its components that I can then leverage in Project LIB. I am currently building/deploying Project A as a private repo and pulling it into Project LIB using `npm install git@github.com:<organization>/<Project A>.git` and that is working fine. My current issue is that only the pages are being build when I build Project A using `npm run build` and it doesn't also generate each component's corresponding `.d.ts` file under `/components`.

I figured setting `"declaration": true /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */` would generate the components for me but that didn't seem to do the trick. I'm also not finding much online regarding how to do this. Maybe i'm just a bad googler, who knows.

Anyways, here's what my `tsconfig` and `package.json` files looks like:

`package.json`:

```
{
...,
"files": [
        "lib/**/*"
    ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "components/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./lib"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which of the two projects is using Next.js?

Comment: @juliomalves Both projects in the provided scenario are using NextJS but based on my client's use case, I decided to migrate the app to a standard react app using CRA and exporting the components that way. It's working well now. Luckily it was in the early stage of development so migrating wasn't tricky

Comment: Yeah - if you want to share React components, you wouldn't want them tied and exported from a Next.js app. They should just live in a separate package which can then be consumed by the Next.js apps.

Comment: Took me longer than I'd like to admit to figure that out. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @Scott have your issue resolved? I am facing similar type of issues

Comment: @Kheersagarpatel I ended up pulling in the entire component repository into a different project as a Github dependency. This allowed me to access all of the internal components of the UI library my client wrote using NextJS.